# Why one of my .CSS files is not opened correctly?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a *web application project* containing several .css files and one of them opens without syntax highlighting and line-breaks.

[image]

When opened with "CSS source editor with encoding" it is displayed correctly (also when double clicked in the Windows Explorer or opene from the Source control history).

[image]

I also opened the file with the "Binary Editor" but I can't see anything wrong.

[image]

The problem is reproduced in VS2010 and VS2012 on three computers (Win7).

What I have attempted so far:
force save file as UNICODE, exclude it from project and include again.

When included in another project the file opens correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was doing the final review before posting I found a solution.
The file tag in .vbproj looks like this

```
<Content Include="filename">
   <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Content>
```

The child tag is added by Visual Studio from an unknown reason: SO:
[<Subtype>Designer</Subtype> Added then removed by Visual Studio on load/unload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573241/subtypedesigner-subtype-added-then-removed-by-visual-studio-on-load-unload)