# In VS 2010, what is the meaning of the "subtype" element in the dbproj file?

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, dbproj

After moving and renaming some files within a database project in VS 2010, I was comparing the dbproj file before and after my changes.  I noticed that in some cases, the element "SubType" changed from "NotInBuild" to "Code", as follows.

from this:

```
<Build Include="...\somefolderpath\filename.proc.sql">
  <SubType>NotInBuild</SubType>
</Build>
```

to this:

```
<Build Include="...\somefolderpath\filename.proc.sql">
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Build>
```

I don't know what I did to cause this change or what the implications are, since I don't know what the SubType element even means.  The SubType of NotInBuild is especially confusing since the solution does actually show that the object is in the build as indicated by its "Build" parent element shown above, also visible when looking at Properties in VS.

Does anyone know what this means and/or what it does?  And specifically, what the values "Code" or "NotInBuild" would mean?  My suspicion is that it is meaningless in a database project, but I would feel better knowing for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio .NET uses the SubType for Form, Component, Designer, UserControl, etc., and may be used to easily to assign the right icon to a form file without having to parse the file. This may be related to the files you have open in the saved solution state.

You may also refer [ProjectSubType Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171386.aspx) and [Designer Added then removed by Visual Studio on load/unload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573241/subtypedesigner-subtype-added-then-removed-by-visual-studio-on-load-unload)

Comment: Any idea what NotInBuild vs. Code means and/or if it has any effect?

Comment: `ProjectSubType` is not relevant, that's something to do with VS templates only.