# Visual Studio Bug - Adding wrong <subtypes> to files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Using VS 2017 I found that it has grown very attached to one C# file and will constantly decorate it with:

`<SubType>Component</SubType>`

int the project file.

The file is just a plain vanilla C# file that has absolutely nothing special; but the IDE treats it as if it was a form.

When I remove this tag, it re-appears.
When I replace the word *Component* by anything else, it comes back.

It does it only to this file.

A google search shows that this is a bug since VS 2015 and it was reported to Microsoft but they never fixed it; Now, with VS 2017, it's still present so I'm not hoping they'll ever fit it, but I'm curious if anyone has found a workaround for this problem?

Comment: is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573241/subtypedesigner-subtype-added-then-removed-by-visual-studio-on-load-unload

Comment: yes, this is the same problem; I found a bunch of posts on google, but none on SO. Looks like there is no real solution.

Comment: Just wondering what aspect of your programming is affected by this issue?

Comment: It's mostly an idea inconvenience: when you click on the file, it won't show you the source anymore as it tries to show a form; you have to right click on the file and then pick 'show source code'. FYI, the file is an async web loading module, and there is not a single form through the entire project, it compiles to a command line tool, so I can't think of any 'tag' that would hint it's a form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<Subtype>Designer</Subtype> Added then removed by Visual Studio on load/unload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573241/subtypedesigner-subtype-added-then-removed-by-visual-studio-on-load-unload)

Comment: @StayOnTarget, I'm not sure, that was 4 years ago and I've completely moved to Rider and dropped VS completely.